# R.styleable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, imageview

hai friends...my java file indicate this error:
R.styleable cannot be resolved....

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
     android:verticalSpacing="5dip" 
     android:horizontalSpacing="5dip" 
     android:columnWidth="80dip" 
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
     android:gravity="center"/> 

 <ImageSwitcher 

    android:id="@+id/switcher" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    </ImageSwitcher>
    <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="HelloGallery">
    <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
    </declare-styleable>
    </resources>


    </LinearLayout>
```

source code:

```
private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
     private int itemBackground;

    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        _context = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle(); 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Hello, Gallery tutorial -- "R.styleable cannot be resolved"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717489/android-hello-gallery-tutorial-r-styleable-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Make sure you explicitly import your R class

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For me, this did the trick:

```
import android.R;
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. REad this answer instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675403/r-styleable-can-not-be-resolved-why

Comment: you can't use android r file , you must use your own created file in gen folder

Answer (score 4):

create an xml file under `values` folder, with the name `attributes.xml` and copy below contents to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Gallery1">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [forum thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg11862.html) you need to change:

```
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
```

to

```
TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
```

Comment: Read the complete thread to see if other ideas are suggested. Also, don't accept the answer, unless it really solves your problem. This will confuse future readers of the question.

Comment: Make sure you explicitly import your R class