# Android: doesn't not recognize styleable in some case

Tags: android, attributes, styleable

I have added some attributes into  file `attr.xml`. Here its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="gallery_view">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground"/>
    </declare-styleable>  

     <declare-styleable name="Dot">
        <attr name="color" format="color"/>
        <attr name="radius" format="dimension"/>
     </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

But I don't why when I use:

`R.styleable.gallery_view_android_galleryItemBackground`: no error.

`R.styleable.Dot_color` will notice error because cannot see this field in R file.

Please help me about this.

Thanks :)

Comment: **The android.R.styleable class and its fields were removed from the public API**, Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675403/r-styleable-can-not-be-resolved-why/6675824#6675824

Comment: Sorry, but at my first case, I still can use it. Explain for me,please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Dot);
a.getColor....
```

Comment: Can you explain more, please. But, I still get the same error when try to get `R.styleable.DOT`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes(int, int[])