# How to set outline border to textview?

Tags: android

I have TextView (word is : "Wed") which I created over xml and I want to set white outline border like on this ss:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Look at this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182393/android-textview-outline-text) Everything is explained here already. Hope you can do it.

Comment: You mean on second anwser with "MagicTextView" or accepted answer?

Comment: You can decide it. Would work both. But I think the "Magic" thing would be that would you are looking for.

Comment: Can't say why. But read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717489/android-hello-gallery-tutorial-r-styleable-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675403/r-styleable-can-not-be-resolved-why

Comment: Solved, I have to create attrs.xml and add there content from this example project

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add the style, like this (taken from source code for Ringdroid):

```
 <style name="AudioFileInfoOverlayText">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
  </style>
```

And in your layout, use the style like this:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText"
       android:gravity="center" />
```

Edit: the source code can be viewed here: http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/

Edit2: To set this style programmatically, you'd do something like this (modified from this example to match ringdroid's resources from above)

```
TextView infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
infoTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),  
       R.style.AudioFileInfoOverlayText);
```

The signature for setTextAppearance is

public void setTextAppearance (Context context, int resid)

Since: API Level 1
Sets the text color, size, style, hint color, and highlight color from the specified TextAppearance resource.