# Problems at R.styleable while integrating native opencv to android studio

Tags: android-ndk, native, android, opencv

I'm addind openCV native lib into my (in developpement) project. I'm following this [guide](https://medium.com/@siantlords/opencv-and-android-ndk-integration-in-android-studio-883a810189e2). I have troubles at the very last step, while building my project, in the OpenCV-android-sdk folder : `CameraGLSurfaceView.java` got error `cannot find symbol variable styleable` at `R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase`.

I have tried to add an `attrs.xml` file in my `values` folder with this content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name = "CameraBridgeViewBase" >
        <attr name="show_fps" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="camera_id" format="integer" >
            <enum name="any" value="-1" />
            <enum name="back" value="2" />
            <enum name="front" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

As it said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675403/r-styleable-can-not-be-resolved-why) quite similar error. But nothing changed when I rebuild my project.

Comment: Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316458/problems-at-r-styleable-while-integrating-native-opencv-to-android-studio/66456218#66456218

Answer (score 13):

In opencv 4 just change

```
res.srcDirs = ['/build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/android_sdk/android_gradle_lib/res']
```

to

```
res.srcDirs = ['res']
```

in the gradle file

Comment: you did the trick man :) trying to find solution since last day :)
thanks

Comment: I've been working on this for 2 days. This is what finally fixed it... wtf

Comment: very great i was trying to import module but attrs file got error i look many times it was showing in the explorer but not in studio after adding this line help me a lot thanks so much you deserve 1000 points for this answer..

Answer (score 6):

In openCv4, you need to make some changes in gradle file of your OPENCV folder(opencv/build.gradle).
Your openCv folder is present in root directory.

ApplicationName->OpenCv->res

Just copy the path and update your gradle file as:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../jni']
                java.srcDirs = ['src']  
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                **res.srcDirs = ['/path-to-your-application/
    ApplicationName/openCv4/res']**
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
  }
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: If you have put OpenCV folder inside of your project folder than you have to write "res.srcDirs=['res']" This solved my problem with OpenCV 4

Comment: What macmuri said above did it for me (although the R.styleable is still underlined with red).

Comment: @Robert You have to give the correct path of openCv4/res to srcDirs

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me with OpenCV4, Try to download [OpenCV3.4](https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-android/3.4.3/opencv-3.4.3-android-sdk.zip)

Comment: That's what I did but it didn't (literally) solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### after importing the module to my project i was getting the error in styleable files as my res folder was not showing to me in android studio but it was showing in file explorer then i know it is something path error in the code.

my error was like this.
[image: i was getting this error]

### how i solved it i just go into the gradle file of open cv library and just change the res dirctory path

from `res.srcDirs = ['/build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/android_sdk/android_gradle_lib/res']`

to

```
res.srcDirs = ['res']
```

and then sync it start working for me and res folder appear in the project file.

[image: start appear]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In openCv4 on Android Studio 4.2 C15 (I'm on SDK 30), the Gradle file of your OPENCV folder(OpenCV/build.Gradle) needs to be like this.
assuming your openCv folder is present in the root directory.

ApplicationName->OpenCv->res

Just copy the path and update your gradle file as:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['build\\intermediates\\library_jni\\debug\\jni']
                java.srcDirs = ['java\\src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['java\\res']
                manifest.srcFile 'java\\AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
  }
```