# Difference between declare-styleable and style

Tags: android, styles, declare-styleable

I've begun playing around with styles and such in my android applications, and I have gotten everything working so far. I quite understood the 'style' [section of the guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

But, looking around, as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717489/android-hello-gallery-tutorial-r-styleable-cannot-be-resolved), I can't really figure out the difference between the two (`declare-stylable` and `style`).
From my understanding `declare-styleable` takes the attribute specified in it and specifies it as styleable, and then from the code one changes it as he wants.

But if this is what it really does, wouldn't it be simpler to just define the attribute in the layout? Or declare a style specifying it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think there is only the following difference between declaring an attribute as styleable or not.

In attrs.xml you can declare custom attributes, either directly within the "resources" section or within "declare-styleable":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <attr name="attrib1" format="string" />
 <declare-styleable name="blahblah">
    <attr name="attrib2" format="string" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

So now we defined "attrib1" as non-styleable and "attrib2" as styleable.

In `layout/someactivity.xml` we can use these attributes directly (no namespace needed):

```
<com.custom.ViewClass  attrib1="xyz" attrib2="abc"/>
```

You can use the "styleable" attribute "attrib2" within a `style.xml` declaration. Again, no namespace is needed here (even if a namespace was used in the layout XML).

```
 <style name="customstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="attrib2">text value</item>
    <!--  customize other, standard attributes too: -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Then you can also set the attributes per style.

```
<com.custom.CustomView attrib1="xyz" style="@style/customstyle"/>
```

Let us assume that we do this: we set `attrib1` directly in XML, and we set `attrib2` in a style.

Elsewhere I have seen descriptions stating that "`blahblah`" must be the name of the custom view class that uses these attributes, and that you need to use a namespace to refer to your custom attributes in the layout XML. But none of this seems to be necessary.

The difference between styleable and non-styleable seems to be that:

- You can use styleable attributes in "`style.xml`" declarations.
- The constructor of the custom class needs to read the styled and the non-styled attributes in a different way: the styled attributes with `obtainStyledAttributes()`, and the non-styled attributes with `attr.getAttributeValue()` or similar.

In most tutorials and examples I've seen on the Web, only the `obtainStyledAttributes()` was used. However, this does not work with attributes declared directly in layout, without using a style. If you do `obtainStyledAttributes()` as shown in most tutorials, you will not get the attribute `attrib1` at all; you will only get `attrib2` since it was declared in the style. The direct method using `attr.getAttributeValue()` works:

```
 public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    String attrib1 = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "attrib1");
    // do something with this value
 }
```

Since we used no namespace to declare "`attrib1`", we pass `null` as the namespace argument in `getAttributeValue()`.

Comment: terrific answer. would up-vote it multiple times if i could.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/baaaf604d23b359a).

Without the `declare-styleable` it would not be possible to create a new custom drawable state.

Comment: So the difference is that declare-styleable gives you the ability to introduce new attributes with which you can do magics like the drawing states (i guess there must be other uses to it) and style simply groups up a set of attributes already existing? Makes sense, thanks.