# Error when add <declare-styleable> tag in Android

Tags: android

Please help me, error at declare-styleable tag: No found tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name=”Gallery1”>
    <attr name=”android:galleryItemBackground” />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585808/difference-between-declare-styleable-and-style

Answer (score 1):

You are using ” instead of ". Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Gallery1">
    <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```