# Why is <declare-styleable> NECESSARY?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been researching this question for a while and haven't found any good answers yet.

I understand how to use `<declare-styleable>`; I understand that use of the AttributeSet methods (e.g., getAttributeValue()) don't resolve references or drill down into `<style>`s; etc.

I think that Winitzki's answer to [Difference between declare-styleable and style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585808/difference-between-declare-styleable-and-style) is exactly on the mark. Using a combination of obtainStyledAttributes and AttributeSet methods will get you most of what you might need.

What I can't figure out is why several different mechanisms are necessary to handle obtaining attributes.

My two (very related) questions are:

1. Couldn't a single method be provided which returns all top-level attributes, drills down into `<style>` elements as necessary and resolves references?
2. Why can't `<attr>`s defined directly within `<resource>` be included in `<style>` elements (and a method provided to access them)? (This another way of asking what `<declare-styleable>` provides.)

Thank you for any help!

Barry

Comment: 1) describes Context.obtainStyledAttributes() and 2) entirely misses the point of passing an array of relevant attributes into obtainStyledAttributes().

Comment: Interesting question although I fear you are slightly confused about how styles work.