# How do I customize the look & feel of a Gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I'm having a hard time understanding how I can create my own Gallery item.  Specifically, I want to alter the appearance of the rectangle that surrounds whatever is the currently selected item (and remove altogether the rectangle that surrounds the non selected items).

Is there a good tutorial on how to create my own styles and pass them into my Widgets?

[Edit]
When initializing my gallery I hand it this

```
R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground
```

and

```
R.styleable.GalleryTheme
```

I'm sure if I could crack those open, I could then copy and alter into what I want.... but where does Android store these?
[/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... this thread answers the actual question:
[Android Hello, Gallery tutorial -- "R.styleable cannot be resolved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717489/android-hello-gallery-tutorial-r-styleable-cannot-be-resolved)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of those themes can most likely be found some where in the [source code of the Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/source/index.html). It'l probably be somewhere [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/) in the resources folder

Comment: oy vey... I guess I was hoping the relevant parts of this would have been covered in some web tutorial... but if no one else chimes in with help... I'll download the source :(

Comment: You can browse the source with the new link I just put in my post. Although I think that link might be a little old. I got it from a privious SO post.